# Vim regex not creating syntax group

Tags: python, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to get the arguments (crudely I just want to highlight anything in the parenthesis) for python functions to highlight. I have a working regex that highlights the right things:

```
syn match pythonArguments "\vdef.*\(\zs.+\ze\)"
hi def link pythonArguments Special
```

Now, I got a similar thing to work in the same document (function calls) with this:

```
syn match pythonFunctionCall "\v\w+\ze\("
hi def link pythonFunctionCall Function
```

But, for some reason the arguments regex won't turn into a syntax group. And I tried running them as a command rather than in my ~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim document to no avail. When my cursor is over expressions which are highlighted by the search `/\vdef.*\(\zs.+\ze\)`, there is no syntax group. I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone interested, it seems that vim (8.1 on MacOS) has buggy syntax groups. I ended up getting it to work with:

```
syn match pythonFunctionDeclaration "\v\(.+\):" contains=ALL transparent
syn match pythonArguments "\v\(\zs.+\ze\)" contained contains=ALL
```

I don't know why the other things that I tried didn't work, but this will highlight python function arguments (and it will leave alone already existing syntax groups).

EDIT:
I learned more. So, the problem with regex for syntax groups is that overlap between different patterns is ignored. For example:

`/\vdef|def something` will match the 'def' part of 'def something' because vim will skip over the 'something' part because it already matched with the first pattern. I don't know if that made any sense, checkout [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/syntax-highlighting-with-multiple-matches-with-zs).

Back to making the highlighting better, the problem with the syntax groups above is that some if statements and for loops will also match. However, this work:

```
syn clear pythonFunction
syn match pythonFunction "\h\w*" 
nextgroup=pythonFunctionDeclaration display contained
syn match pythonFunctionDeclaration "\v\(.+\):" contains=pythonArguments transparent contained
syn match pythonArguments "\v\(\zs.+\ze\)" contained contains=ALLBUT,pythonFunction
hi def link pythonArguments Special
```

This will make our special syntax group only happen after functions.

TLDR; add the second (the longer) block of code to you ~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim file to make python function arguments highlighted the same as the Special syntax group is highlighted.